# Why would a control be on a different thread from the one I'm working in?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm not (intentionally) using threads in my C# app. In fact my main method has a `[STAThread]`, which I thought meant I'd only be using one thread.

Why then, would I be getting this error message?

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'messageLog' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of types which can cause your code to run on different threads without any explicit call to `System.Threading`.  In particular `FileSystemWatcher` and `BackgroundWorker` come to mind.  Are you using any of these types?

Also `STAThread` in no way limits the ability of your process to spawn threads.  It instead sets the COM apartment type of the initial application thread.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer being another

Comment: @Nos I am using timers - I guess that's what's caused it.

Comment: Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer if this is a winfoms application, it'll dispatch timer events to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Marking your `main` method with `[STAThread]` does not mean that you cannot spawn additional threads.

You don't really provide any information about what is triggering your code, so I can't be more specific, but any time you execute asynchronous code it will take place on another thread. Doing things like `BeginInvoke` on a delegate (or, for that matter, most methods that start with `Begin`--and definitely if they return an `IAsyncResult`--are async methods) will execute the code (and the callback) on another thread.

If you can provide some more detail about your situation, I can try to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

`[STAThread]` does not indicate that your application will be single threaded. It only indicates that the application will use threading a manner that allows other threads to execute while a particular thread is waiting for a time-consuming operation to complete.

As to why the cross threading exception is being thrown, a little more context is needed. What type of control is messageLog? What code accesses this control? Are you using any other controls that implicitly use threads (such as a `BackgroundWorker`)?